# ssh connection nornir_napalm via rsa

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I am quite new to nornir and network automation but I am in stuck with following scenario.
`ssh` via using ssh key. Using access via password works without problem.
My `hosts.yaml` look like this

```
---
  juniper-tst:
      hostname: 10.0.0.12
      port: 22
      username: mario
      platform: junos
```

But I keep getting this error

```
ncclient.transport.errors.AuthenticationError: SSHException('encountered RSA key, expected OPENSSH key',)
```

Now I am not sure if any extra  optional argument is needed to be inserted in the `hosts.yaml`.

versions:

```
Python3.6
Nornir 3.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the format of your private key. You should know that there are openssh format and PEM format. Both will work when connecting to openssh server but some libssh based applications may be picky (I had issue with zabbix ssh).

You are using the "PEM format" which starts with "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

just generate an new set of keys with ssh-keygen which default to the OPENSSH format which starts with "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----"

Comment: Thanks, yeah i just check and indeed I am suing the PEM format. Now is there any way to simply translate the format from RAS to OPENSSH? I mean idea is that i can not generate a new pair of private/publick key as than i need to push my new public key to all my devices where i need to connect to. I hoe make sense what i wrote. Thanks!

Comment: I am NOt SURE yet but you might have to operate on both public and private keys. See here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32768/converting-keys-between-openssl-and-openssh